# How to move file pointer to previous line in php?

Tags: php, while-loop, fseek, feof

Text file in question is named fp.txt and contains 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, ...10 on each line.

```
01
02
...
10
```

Code:

```
<?php
//test file for testing fseek etc
$file = "fp.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r+") or die("Couldn't open ".$file);
$count = 0;
while(!(feof($fp))){ // till the end of file
    $text = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $count++;
    $dice = rand(1,2); // just to make/alter the if condition randomly
    echo "Dice=".$dice." Count=".$count." Text=".$text."<br />";
    if ($dice == 1){
        fseek($fp, -1024, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

So, because of fseek($fp, -1024, SEEK_CUR); is not  working properly. What I want is that If Dice == 1, set the file-pointer to previous line i.e. one line up than the current one. But I think negative value is setting the file pointer to end of file, and thus ending the while loop before the actual end of file.

Desired Output is:

```
Dice=2 Count=1 Text=01 
Dice=2 Count=2 Text=02
Dice=2 Count=3 Text=03
Dice=1 Count=4 Text=03
Dice=2 Count=5 Text=04
Dice=2 Count=6 Text=05
Dice=2 Count=7 Text=06
Dice=1 Count=8 Text=06
Dice=1 Count=9 Text=06
Dice=2 Count=10 Text=07
....                                    //and so on until Text is 10 (Last Line)
Dice=2 Count=n Text=10
```

Note that whenever dice is 2, text is same as previous one. Now it is just stopping at the first occurrence of Dice=1

So basically my question is How to move/relocate file-pointer to previous line?

Please note that dice=rand(1,2) is just for example. In the actual code, $text is a string and if condition is to be true when string does not contain a particular text.

EDIT:
Solved, both samples (@hakre 's & mine) are working as desired.

Comment: It will be easier if you convert the file to array with [`file()`](http://php.net/file) and manipulate the array.

Comment: I was going to add the comment that file can contain 1000+ lines. So loading all of the file once in a single array would be not optimal I think.

Comment: Are all the lines in the file of a known length, or at least a known range of possible lengths?

Comment: @DaveRandom the lines contain Roll Numbers of Students. May contain alphabets and numbers. Maybe max 50 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = "fp.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r+") or die("Couldn't open ".$file);
$eof = FALSE; //end of file status
$count = 0;
while(!(feof($fp))){ // till the end of file
    $current = ftell($fp);
    $text = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $count++;
    $dice = rand(1,2); // just to alter the if condition randomly
    if ($dice == 2){
            fseek($fp, $current, SEEK_SET);
    }
    echo "Dice=".$dice." Count=".$count." Text=".$text."<br />";
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This sample is also working as required.

The changes are:

```
* Addition of "$current = ftell($fp);" after while loop.
* Modification of fseek line in if condition.
* checking for dice==2 instead of dice==1
```

Answer (score 4):

You read out a line from the file, but only forward to the next line when the dice is not 1.

Consider to use the [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/SPLFileObject) for that, which offers an interface that is better for your scenario I'd say:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("fp.txt");
$count = 0;
$file->rewind();    
while ($file->valid())
{
    $count++;
    $text = $file->current();
    $dice = rand(1,2); // just to make alter the if condition randomly
    echo "Dice=".$dice." Count=".$count." Text=".$text."<br />";
    if ($dice != 1)
    {
       $file->next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked as required. Also I found out that making the following modifications as explained in my answer makes it to work as required.

Comment: ah, now seeing you added an answer.